# TextArea: Add event listener for setting the font and size

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am programming a text editor in javafx. I want to set font and size to entered letters in `TextArea`. I should add a listener, so that every letter entered will be written in the specified font and size. If I change the font, the new letters will only be written with this new font.

What methods should I use?

```
TextArea Area = new TextArea();
```

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried.

Comment: [mcve] please ... we are not going to do _your_ assignment for you ;)

Comment: JavaFX's `TextArea` does not support rich text. All text has to have the same style, including font.

Comment: RichtextFX or [`HTMLEditor`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) are capable of this; `TextArea` is not...

Comment: As Slaw said, all text in a TextArea is forced to use the same font at all times.  You cannot change that.  Try an [HTMLEditor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) instead.

Comment: Ok thnx for answers i got it now